# Why is the Python Multiprocessing Manager().Queue maxsize parameter not passed?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

Could it be that setting the `maxsize` of `Queue` started by a `Manager` has no effect whatsoever?
For example, I can create a queue like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
queue = mp.Manager().Queue(maxsize=10)
```

However, when inspecting the actual source of the `SyncManager` I see the following:

```
class SyncManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):

    # [...]

    def Queue(self, maxsize=None):
        return queue.Queue()
```

Why is the maximum size not passed? Why does the parameter even exist in this case?